# How do i UIWebView in Xcode4

Tags: xcode

I want to build a application in xcode4 which will load a page in app inside. 
I am following the bellow video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yICZb91Poxs
Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is not a question. There are loads of tutorials about how to set up and use a UIWebView. If you try one and have a specific issue then update your question with the details + code.

Answer (score 1):

You create a project and in your .h you write :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webV;
```

Don't forget the `@synthesize`

And in your .m :

```
[webV loadRequest:[NSRLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.fr"]]];
```

You can replace of course google.fr by another adress.